# Python 3 lxml ImportError on CentOS 6.4

Tags: python, lxml, python-3.3, python-import

CentOS 6.4 on my desktop had python 2.6.6 already installed

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python


$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb 22 2013, 00:00:18) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I installed python 3.3.0 from source side-by-side to the existing python 2.6.6 version.

However, when I am trying to use the lxml module in python 3, I get a ImportError as below:

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3


$ python3
Python 3.3.0 (default, Oct  8 2012, 21:38:46) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'lxml'
>>>
```

Any pointers on how do I get the lxml module under python 3.3.0 would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install lxml [for each Python version you want to use it with](http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/newbie-hint-on-installing-python-and-its-modules-and-packages/).

Comment: Lennart - The link in your reply helped me. Thank you Sir.
# /usr/local/bin/easy_install lxml
# python3
Python 3.3.0 (default, Oct  8 2012, 21:38:46) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lxml import etree
>>>